# wcf wait for object to become available

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, locking

I am a newbie programmer, I'm writing a WCF project using c#. On my server side, it accepts calls and does some complicated process. However, I want to make sure certain process is finished before the server execute another call. To make my problem easier to understand, I will make a similar process here but simpler. For example, the server will do some complicated calculation, then log-in on a website, post a status, and log-out the website, and do some more calculation. I don't care if multiple thread (client call) is running at the same time while it is doing the calculation. But I DO care when the {login,post,logout} part is executed, because they all use the same credentials to login the website, so if more than one thread is trying to login at the same time, the website will reject.

```
[ServiceBehavior(
ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single,
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class WCFProject
{
    ComplicatedCalculation();

    Login();    
    Post();
    Logout();

    SomeMoreCalculation();
}
```

I want to make sure, if Jeff's client call is executing the login() post() logout(), all other client call will wait if they reach this part of code, and continues when jeff's call finishes that 3 methods. And then execute those 3 method one client at a time. Is there a way to achieve this? will the lock() or using() statement work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The client is on pc, and there will be multiple clients from different PCs.

Comment: what is the context here? where are the multiple clients? on different machines? (desktop app) - or on the same machine ? (asp.net etc) Also: could you not just change the WCF API to take (secured, etc) credentials? rather than login/post/logout

Comment: my problem is a more complicated process, but here we will assume that only one credential can be used.

Comment: is that per underlying connection? or is it "global"? because if the latter, and you have multiple web-servers, then it may be unfixable. Indeed, even on a single server ASP.NET can overlap app-domains

Comment: sorry if I'm not clear, my problem is not about the website, the website is just an similar situation of what I want to do, I want to make sure other calls will WAIT while one call is executing the login/post/logout.

Comment: I think that you can do it simply in thedefinition of methods, e.g. when login is called some flag 'login' is set and no more login methods can be executed, the same for post, and in logout you just reset the flags for login and post.

Comment: @GuangLu it sounds like you want to look into a `Semaphore` of count 1, or a `ManualResetEvent`. You can probably also just use `lock`.